# emacs closes when terminal closes

Tags: command-line, emacs

I open a file with  emacs through terminal just typing

```
emacs file.txt
```

and when I close terminal, emacs closes too, and when I try to execute another thing terminal doesn't let me becuase keeps like this:

[image]

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a terminal to run emacs, the use the command below

```
emacs file.txt & nohup
```

---

From `man nohup`

```
nohup - 
run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous method you can use `setsid`:

```
setsid emacs file.txt
```

`man setsid`

setsid - run a program in a new session